# Inconsistent Compiling in Visual Studio with extern variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I want to define a few variables as global, however i found a few problems.
The code below compiles sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. In this case it wasn't working so i copy pasted the code here, after that i deleted everything inside the files rebuilt the solution and pasted everything back and it worked.

But it actualy didn't this time only by removing the namespace and defining everything outside in the GlobalData.cpp could the code be compiled. ok, but if i cleaned the solution it would not compile however if i added the namespace back it worked. but, again, if i cleaned solution and recompiled it would not work.

So i have no idea of what is happening.

For clarification the error is always about defining the variables twice, in both of the cases with or without the namespace.

Code:

// GLOBALDATA.h

```
#pragma once
#include <bitset>
#ifndef GLOBALDATA_H
#define GLOBALDATA_H

namespace GlobalData
{
extern std::bitset<64> PieceBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> PawnBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> KnightBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> BishopBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> RookBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> QueenBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> KingBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> ColorWhiteBoard;
extern std::bitset<64> ColorBlackBoard;
}

#endif // !GLOBALDATA_H
```

---

// GLOBALDATA.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include "GLOBALDATA.h"

namespace GlobalData
{
std::bitset<64> PieceBoard;
std::bitset<64> PawnBoard;
std::bitset<64> KnightBoard;
std::bitset<64> BishopBoard;
std::bitset<64> RookBoard;
std::bitset<64> QueenBoard;
std::bitset<64> KingBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorWhiteBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorBlackBoard;
}
```

---

// Board.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GLOBALDATA.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

}
```

As i said i tried to find the problem, but both versions of the code "worked" until i rebuilt the solution or cleaned it and compiled it again.

---

// GLOBALDATA.cpp v1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include "GLOBALDATA.h"

namespace GlobalData
{
std::bitset<64> PieceBoard;
std::bitset<64> PawnBoard;
std::bitset<64> KnightBoard;
std::bitset<64> BishopBoard;
std::bitset<64> RookBoard;
std::bitset<64> QueenBoard;
std::bitset<64> KingBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorWhiteBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorBlackBoard;
}
```

---

// GLOBALDATA.cpp v2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include "GLOBALDATA.h"

std::bitset<64> PieceBoard;
std::bitset<64> PawnBoard;
std::bitset<64> KnightBoard;
std::bitset<64> BishopBoard;
std::bitset<64> RookBoard;
std::bitset<64> QueenBoard;
std::bitset<64> KingBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorWhiteBoard;
std::bitset<64> ColorBlackBoard;
```

---

Exemple error (there was one for each variable)

```
Error   LNK2005 "class std::bitset<64> PieceBoard" (?PieceBoard@@3V?$bitset@$0EA@@std@@A) already defined in GLOBALDATA.obj Xadrez  C:\Users\X\source\repos\Xadrez\Tabuleiro.obj    1
```

Anyone can replicate?

Comment: No you think you want some global variables. In the end you probably don't. You might want some global constants `namespace chess::pieces { inline constexpr std::bitset<64> PieceBoard{0x0001};`.  Really try to avoid global variables accross translation units they create an implicit dependency between unrelated pieces of code use setters/getters and/or dependency injection to spread information throughout your code.

Comment: `#include "GLOBALDATA.cpp"` Don't do this. You likely meant `#include "GLOBALDATA.h"`. Headers are meant to be included; source files are not.

Comment: Thank you both, for the sugestions. Im new to c++ so i had no idea what was wrong. But still why would it compile once and stop compiling again?